# PDOStatement::execute(): Unknown type 245 sent by the server. Please send a report to the developers

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

When I query for the JSON columns in MySQL 5.7.14 and laravel 5.2, I face the below error:

> PDOStatement::execute(): Unknown type 245 sent by the server. Please send a report to the developers

The query is:

```
select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(config_settings,"$.description")) as description FROM example.
```

Comment: Have you sent the report to the developers? What did they answer?

Comment: no. actually Database client version: libmysql was older version in my machine. so i upgraded it and then its works fine.

Comment: @ChiruAdi I am using Laravel and getting error `PDO::prepare(): Unknown type 245 sent by the server. Please send a report to the developers`, how did you sort it out?

Answer (score 3):

I observed that this warning occurs when using an old version of PHP (5.5.38) with a mysql table having JSON fields.

Changing the JSON fields to good old TEXT solves the problem.